# Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established Node.js v13.0.1

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When id add exports.create=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=> and run command firebase deploy shows this result

```
functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (40.37 KB) for uploading
!  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

please check the code below.....

````
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');


var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAzf0Y4k7qvkWSWkwgsYjH9mrnFa_P9xt4",
    authDomain: "fir-test-dc973.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-test-dc973.firebaseio.com/",
    storageBucket: "gs://fir-test-dc973.appspot.com/"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);


exports.create=functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{

  var data=JSON.parse(req.body);
  var user_id=data.user_id;

var language_id=data.language_id;
  firebase.database().ref("game_room/").orderByChild("availability").equalTo(1).limitToFirst(1).once('value', ((snapshot)=> {
     console.log("user_id  ",user_id);


    if (snapshot.val() !== null) {
            console.log("available");
            var childKey = Object.keys(snapshot.val());
            console.log("gameroom   ", childKey);


            const userQuery = firebase.database().ref(`game_room/${childKey}`).once('value');
            const language_id1 = userQuery.val().language_id;
            if (language_id === language_id1) {
                 firebase.database().ref(`game_room/${childKey}/${user_id}`).update({
                        "status": true,
                        "right": 0,
                        "wrong": 0,
                        "que_no": 0,
                        "sel_ans": "",
                    });
                  firebase.database().ref(`game_room/${childKey}`).update({
                        "availability": 2,

                    });

                }else{
                    createGameRoom();
                }

            console.log(snapshot.val());
        }
    else
    {

        createGameRoom();


    }

    }));


  function createGameRoom() {
    console.log("not available");
                var ref=firebase.database().ref('game_room/').push({
                    "availability":1,  
                    "language_id":language_id,


                    });

                        console.log(ref.key);
                        var key=ref.key;
                            console.log(key);
                         var ref1= firebase.database().ref(`game_room/${key}/${user_id}`).update({//.push({
                                    //ref.set({
                                "status":true,
                            "right":0,
                            "wrong":0,
                            "que_no":0,
                            "sel_ans":"",

                                });




}
 res.send({"code":user_id});
});```

log is here 
[debug] [2020-01-03T13:50:53.722Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2020-01-03T13:50:53.725Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-46ce5050-804a-4464-a2b2-569f0e4aaa93/75a761e4-936f-4b66-8f59-bb043b386f8d.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-853915451227@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1578061220&Signature=KBV5Gmv3OObNlC8%2BuCwYptBWjPI%2BhGblYX644ugU15FPwwFITQ3VDSIM7%2F9xsK2UqjFhdjx8s2inymbffxoemRmN1mKqPbHGP0ZFCy%2FDQUAHR%2FUccF%2FtRBiG2EQ0oaU5m9T7NoTs1NnVmDNhGz25mIGNdkO0efv8ZOqfXCYOSLV1jbgQtUGv%2FB%2ButjsTB3b6nxBOwHj7HbsFt1pB4uqGmVitGxj0JvxOhSAK6pCWXrsbWgL%2FnnoktYhhyMWFt9YgTSdWB36OeigQCdVldRVIodpaa3aShfDwMRPQCktgQQWZX0tAPsScs62i5Y11PLvSk2VeGxFFZgAyEA1XrzPjyg%3D%3D  
 <request body omitted>
[warn] !  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
[debug] [2020-01-03T13:51:04.100Z] Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:575:14)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1361:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:478:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1198:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
[error] 
[error] Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
````

Comment: is there any solution? I have been faced with the same problem. didn't get any solutions last 24 hours.

Comment: Yes there network issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might have had some sort of network error during deployment.  When the CLI generates error messages like this that don't offer a clear resolution, you should [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for troubleshooting.